# How many if statements can be executed in 1 sec approximately

Tags: performance, if-statement, cpu, processor

I am planning to write a project that includes 10 for-loops and uses the for-loops more than 10000 times. So, there are about 10000 * 10^10 if statements. At the end of the for-loop, there is a result. My project is to get the best result from the 10 for-loops. I will write my project in Java.

I am thinking is it possible to calculate the results?

My computer hardware performance is below

Macbook air early 2014

Processor: 1.4GHz Intel I5

Memory: 4GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Also, what is the calculation method to find it out?

Comment: Try timing it with a smaller number of iterations, then work out how long it will take with the intended number of iterations.

Comment: i think you should be more concerned about the work that is done in the body of the for-loops. And besides if-statements incrementing loop counters and memory access also takes time. It also depends on the programming language you choose.

Comment: #1 rule of performance testing: measure. That is: try it. Anything else is made up.

Comment: Is there any website you guys would suggest for me to take a look how to implement a performance testing?

Comment: @PakHoCheung Start a timer. Run the code with a small number of iterations. Stop the timer. If you get bored waiting for it, reduce the number of iterations and try again.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:  It all depends on the code, and what asm output the compiler makes.  I assume a recent MacBook uses an Intel Haswell CPU, so I've used that as an example.

Update: I didn't notice that you said Java.  Take all the uncertainty and hand-waving in the text below and square it, because a good JIT-compiler will take advantage of dynamic information to do stuff like check the most common condition first.  Optimizing the code for the data it's actually running on can make a big difference, esp. for a small loop that runs for a long time.

---

Mapping of C statements to asm instructions is nowhere near 1:1.  Depending on the conditions being tested, the compiler might combine some tests together, or not even use branches.

If the expression in the `if()` condition is complex, it will typically take multiple instructions to evaluate it.  Every clause separated by `&&` or `||` might result in a separate conditional branch, to implement short-circuit evaluation.

Intel SnB-family CPUs can sustain a throughput of four uops per clock.  Intel Haswell and later can macro-fuse two compare-and-branch pairs in each decode-block of 4 to 6 instructions (up from one macro-fusion per cycle in previous uarches).  (See [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/), and other stuff at the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).  So in theory a Haswell CPU can issue 3 compare-and-branch instruction pairs per clock.  It can only execute two conditional branches per clock, though (as long as they're both correctly predicted, and at least one of them is not-taken).

You can use perf counters to see if your code is saturating port6 (taken branches) or ports 0 and 6 (not-taken branches).  Or more likely, whether you're suffering from pipeline stalls due to branch mispredicts.

Looking at the asm output from the compiler is one first step in seeing what the compiler can make of your code.  Sometimes it can help you see source changes that will get that particular compiler to emit better code.  Sometimes you can see a more optimal way for the asm to flow, and can write the source in a way that reflects that, which will hopefully help any compiler.

Comment: Its ok. I understand your concept and what I should do. Thank you for your help:)